# Convert Datetime format to varchar format style workaround

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a datetime column that I need to display in the following format:

```
YYYY/MM/DD 00:00:00:000
```

With `CONVERT`, I can't find any suitable styles.

The `/` in the format is really important as it needs to be compared with a `VARCHAR` column that has text `YYYY/MM/DD 00:00` as part of the description like below:

If I can find a way/style then I can use a SUBSTRING function to compare it to the value below:

```
Diary item added for : 2013/08/20 14:12
```

I have had a look at:

http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-are-the-valid-styles-for-converting-datetime-to-string.html

But, I can't find any sufficient styles that has / 's.  Only -'s.

Comment: Do you have a time part? or do you care only for the date part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the style that most closely resembles what you want to compare on and use  `REPLACE` to replace the `-` with `\`.

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(<yourstyle>),'-','/');
```

---

**Edit** *Cudo's to @bluefeet*

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(23), yourdate, 121),'-','/');
```

From [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx): Cast and Convert

> 21 or 121 (2)   ODBC canonical (with milliseconds)  yyyy-mm-dd
>   hh:mi:ss.mmm(24h)

Comment: Use this along with style 121 and you should get the result -  `select REPLACE(convert(varchar(23), yourdate, 121),'-','/')` - [see demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/19709)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted @Lieven Keersmaekers, thank you.  Adding a substring around the statement in your comment I managed to get the date output as YYYY/MM/DD 00:00.  SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(convert(varchar(23), MY_Date, 121),'-','/'), 1, 16) FROM Table.

Comment: @frans - Using `SUBSTRING` is the most readable and maintainable solution but if you like it shortened, you could also convert to a `varchar(16)` and get the same results.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can convert both Dates in any format before you compare the two just use any of these: run this and you can select from them, make sure to convert both dates before Comparing

```
Select    
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 100) as '100 Conversion',    
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 101) as '101 Conversion',    
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 102) as '102 Conversion',    
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 103) as '103 Conversion',    
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 104) as '104 Conversion',    
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 105) as '105 Conversion',    
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 106) as '106 Conversion',    
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 107) as '107 Conversion',    
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 108) as '108 Conversion',    
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 109) as '109 Conversion',    
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 110) as '110 Conversion',    
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 111) as '111 Conversion',    
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 112) as '112 Conversion',    
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 113) as '113 Conversion',    
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 114) as '114 Conversion',    
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 120) as '120 Conversion',    
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 121) as '121 Conversion',    
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 126) as '126 Conversion',    
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 130) as '130 Conversion',    
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 131) as '131 Conversion'
```

Or Use this

```
select REPLACE(convert(varchar, GetDate(), 121),'-','/')
```

Comment: please stop using `varchar` with no length. [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: im just demonstrating the use of it, the answer is not particular about using varchar with no length, it is for Franz question.

Comment: fwiw - you should not be adding a solution already posted by someone else without giving credit for it.

Answer (score 2):

Why cant you do the reverse. Convert the varchar column to date instead of converting date to varchar

Comment: We are already getting the varchar column with a substring.  Converting that substring back to a datetime would give YYYY/MM/DD 00:00:00:000 again, which would again have to be substring'ed?  Also something to remember for future though.  Thanks @Mani